# Check text file content in PowerShell

Tags: powershell

The **PowerShell** command

```
Get-ADFSRelyingPartyTrust | select Name | out-file C:\listOfNames.txt
```

generates a file as follows:

```
Name
----
AustriaRP
BahamasRP
BrazilRP
CanadaRP

[...]
```

Now, how can I check if `BrazilRP` has been extracted and `C:\listOfNames.txt` contains it?

Comment: `(gc C:\listOfNames.txt) -contains 'BrazilRP'`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I found a solution (but thanks to **PiotrWolkowski** to suggest me the `Get-Content` function):

```
$file = Get-Content "C:\listOfNames.txt"
$containsWord = $file | %{$_ -match "BrazilRP"}
if ($containsWord -contains $true) {
    Write-Host "There is!"
} else {
    Write-Host "There ins't!"
}
```

Answer (score 9):

The `Get-Content` and then `Select-String` should help. If the string is in the file it will get returned. If not then the command will returned empty value.

```
Get-Content C:\listOfNames.txt | Select-String "BrazilRP"
```

If the "BrazilRP" occurs more than once all the occurrences will returned so you know if you got any duplicates. Same holds if the string is a part of a longer expression. For example if you search for "zil" then "Bra**zil**RP" will be returned as well.

Also you can pipe the results out to another file:

```
Get-Content C:\listOfNames.txt | Select-String "BrazilRP" | Out-File C:\myResults.txt
```

Answer (score -1):

If you want to easily see if a file contains your text try this

The [bool] type returns the data as either true or false instead of returning the actual data your searching for

```
if ([bool]((Get-Content -Path "C:\listOfNames.txt") -like '*BrazilRP*')) { 
write-host "found it"
}
else {
 write-host "didnt find it"
}
```